# Filetype specific linespace setting

Tags: vim, markdown, macvim

I would like to have a higher number in my `linespace` setting for markdown files for easier reading. I thought I'd do in my `.vimrc`:

```
au FileType markdown setlocal linespace=4
```

But no luck. The locality of the setting is ignored and `linespace` is applied to all buffers (even Python and Javascript files).

I'm using Pope's `markdown.vim` plugin to provide the markdown filetype.

Ideas?

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved the question or leave a comment with further explanation and we'll look into solving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually *linespace* is a global option (see `:h linespace`). Your auto command
is working, but even though it's using `:setlocal`, the option can't be applied to
a specific buffer or window; acting as if you had used `:set`.

---

#### Update

If you want to change the *linespace* option based on your current buffer, basically
all you need to do is changing your current auto-command from

```
au FileType markdown setlocal linespace=4
```

To

```
au BufEnter *.markdown setlocal linespace=4
```

The difference is that now the command will be auto called when you enter a buffer
that has a file name ending with `.markdown` (change this pattern to match your
usual mardown extension).

To reset the option, add the following auto-command as well to your *.vimrc*:

```
au BufLeave *.markdown setlocal linespace=2
```

It will set the *linespace* option to 2 (or whatever value you want) once you leave
a buffer containing a markdown file.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem? Make a quick toggle function to put into vimrc? Thanks

Comment: @Honza Pokorny: Not sure if I got it, but really solving the problem would involve a heavy patch to Vim code and MacVim drawing system as well. So, let's consider it's not "possible" to have different line spaces at the same time. However, to toggle the setting based on the current buffer, check my updated answer. Hope that helps!